# How do I create a name tag that appears upon clicking a model in a 3-D viewer?

Tags: javascript, three.js, webgl

I loaded individual STL structures into my 3-D viewer using three.js and I want to be able to click on individual structures in my 3-D viewer and a name tag appears onMouseClick or onMouseOver for that specific structure.

I think it has something to do with a coordinate point of that specific object or maybe just the total surface area of that object and then use a onMouseClick eventHandler to create a window but I'm not sure.

Is there any sample or open source code I can take a look at?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check any of the collision detection examples in the examples folder. Probably webgl_interactive_cubes.html is what you're after: 
http://mrdoob.github.com/three.js/examples/webgl_interactive_cubes.html

This will show you how to find which element is behind the mouse.

I also wrote a tutorial on picking objects with three.js if you want to know a bit more about how the thing works internally:
http://soledadpenades.com/articles/three-js-tutorials/object-picking/

Then --you already know where the mouse is from the mousemove or mouseclick event-- just create a span or something similar, and place it in that position with css's left and top properties, for example

Comment: Soledad - Nice tutorial! pickingRay has problems, though. See https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/2453

Comment: Thanks, glad you liked it! Also, interesting to know that pickingRay is not without fault! Good to have people using the library in so many ways, it's a very good test :-D

Comment: Great thanks. Actually, I'm really looking for something like the canvas interactive cubes example. So, essentially the vital function is onDocumentMouseDown( event ); This function will detect the click of a mouse and generate the particle correct?

Comment: Yes, that function creates a particle in the position where the intersection was detected, and adds it to the scene :-)

Comment: What's interesting is that when I put onDocumentMouseDown(event) in my viewport.js, I get an error saying viewport isn't defined even though when I don't add that function, my viewer works fine :/

Comment: Hard to say without seeing your code. Seems like you're copying stuff but have missed something.